# How do I get the variant_dir path from inside a Builder()?

Tags: scons

I'm writing a custom Builder. Is there any way from inside the Builder to get the root path of the variant_dir it's building in?

Maybe a property on env?

Or maybe from a target node? For example, if in my Builder I have:

```
target[0].path --> path_to/my_variant_dir/subdir/target_file.txt
```

Is there a way to determine which part is the variant_dir path?

```
'path_to/my_variant_dir'
```

Comment: What's the use model?

Comment: @bdbaddog If you invoke `SConscript(dirs='foo')` without passing `variant_dir =` , from an `SConscript` file that *was* invoked with `variant_dir`, the resulting variant dir will be first-variant-dir + 'foo'. I refer to this as automatic variant dir "stacking".  It might be nice, from the lower SConscript to know what the automatically stacked variant dir is. (Say I want to invoke yet another SConscript, but I want to specify his variant dir. Well if I want it to be a subdirectory of my current variant dir, I need to know what that is.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify the variant dir in the call to SConscript() so you can just store it on the env and retrieve it later. Ive actually done this before for a different reason, like this:

```
var_dir = 'some_dir'
env['variant_dir'] = var_dir

SConscript('subdir/SConscript', variant_dir = env['variant_dir'], duplicate = 0)
...

def yourBuilderFunc(target, source, env):
   # variant_dir is env['variant_dir']
```